# Create getter for JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript

Hopefully, what I'm trying to do is possible. I'm trying to create a getter for any objects, inside an object.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Object.defineProperty(Settings.Data['_' + type], name, {
    get: function(){
        return Settings.__Data['_' + type][name];
    },
    set: function(value){
        Settings.__Data['_' + type][name] = value;
        console.log('__Data._' + type + '.' + name + ': Updated!');
        console.log(Settings.__Data['_' + type][name]);
    }
});
```

This works correctly when I set the Object like this:

```
Settings.Data['_' + type][name] = "test";
```

But not when I do:

```
Settings.Data['_' + type][name].test = "test";
```

I thought it would of works as your technically changing the `Settings.Data['_' + type][name]` property, but apparently not.

Is is possible to create a object with getter's and setter's that also get used for the next level of objects (like above)?

Comment: If you're using modern JavaScript (ES6), perhaps you'd be better off with a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Comment: "*as your technically changing the property*" - no, you *access* it and then  mutate the returned object by setting a property inside it

Comment: You want `Settings.Data['_' + type][name] = { test: "test" };`?

Comment: @trincot That would work, but not for the solution I'm looking as I'm wanting to be able to add to the object, I guess I could read [name] each time and then write it back, but I was hoping for something cleaner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a kind of flexible object, which will not return `undefined` when a non-existing property is accessed, but which will create that property on-the-fly and make its value also such a flexible object.

You can do this with an ES6 Proxy:

```js
function FlexObject() {
    return new Proxy({}, {
        get: function (target, key) {
            // If this key does not exist, create it on the fly
            if (!(key in target)) target[key] = FlexObject()
            // ... and now return its value as if it had already been there
            return target[key];
        }
    });
}

// Demo
var Settings = FlexObject();

var type = "mytype",
    name = "myname";
Settings.Data['_' + type][name].test = "ok";

console.log(Settings.Data['_' + type][name].test); // ok
```

Be aware though that once you assign a value to a property, that property will not have the previous flexibility any more. So after executing the above code, you will get an error when you do this:

```
Settings.Data['_' + type][name].test.deeper.andDeeper = "too deep";
```

If you want to restore the flexibility on that `test` property after having assigned a value to it, you must either delete it, or explicitly assign `FlexObject()` to it:

```
delete Settings.Data['_' + type][name].test;
Settings.Data['_' + type][name].test.deeper.andDeeper = "works!";
```